# Что такое: 2 физических / 2 логических ядра?

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте.

Выделенный сервер с процессором Intel Atom D525. В описании к серверу сказано: это двухъядерный процессор ... но благодаря технологии HyperThreading, способен обработать четыре потока за один раз. Как это понять?

Вообщем моя проблема в том, что я не знаю какое значение установить для директивы worker_processes в конфигурационном файле nginx.conf

worker_processes 2; ИЛИ worker_processes 4;

Ведь по Сысоеву worker_processes должен равняться числу процессорных ядер.

Помогите подсчитать ядра :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот в документации прямо об этом написано:

```
worker_processes    2;worker_cpu_affinity 0101 1010;binds the first worker process to CPU0/CPU2, and the second worker process to CPU1/CPU3. The second example is suitable for hyper-threading.
```

[ссылка на доку](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes)

Answer (score 0):

Количество физических ядер же 2. А логические это ядра которые настроены самим процессором, они не имеют отдельной "микросхемы". Поэтому пишите 2.